# Datatables - Date Age - Filter ASC DESC

Tags: jquery, datatable

I hava a Datatable with an age Column where I calculate the age of an entry.

This is my script for the column:

```
{
                    data: "created_on",
                    render: function (d) {
                        var date = moment(d).format("YYYY.MM.DD");
                        var time = moment(d);

                        var eventdate = moment(date);
                        var todaydate = moment();

                        var eventtime = moment(time);
                        var todaytime = moment();

                        if(todaydate.diff(eventdate, 'days') == "0"){

                            if(todaytime.diff(eventtime, 'hours') == "0") {

                                return todaytime.diff(eventtime, 'minutes') + " Min";

                            } else {

                                const min = todaytime.diff(eventtime, 'minutes') - (todaytime.diff(eventtime, 'hours') * 60);
                                return todaytime.diff(eventtime, 'hours') + " Std " + min +  " Min";
                            }
                                
                        } else if (todaydate.diff(eventdate, 'days') == "1") {
    
                            return todaydate.diff(eventdate, 'days') + " Tag";
    
                        } else {
    
                            return todaydate.diff(eventdate, 'days') + " Tage";
                        }
                    },
                    width: '100px',
                },
```

It works on calculation the age but the problem is now that it filters not correctly via asc desc.

[image]

What can I do about it? Or is there an easier way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

try to sort using html5 data attributes (https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html)

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Alter</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-sort="31">31 Tage</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-sort="30">30 Tage</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```